# Приложение не появляется в эмуляторе

Tags: android

Собственно изучал себе спокойно андроид. Делал всякие  activity  layouts для них. Тестил в эмуляторе, который был в android-sdk пакете (extras/intel).

Все бы хорошо, однако в один прекрасный момент вышло каким-то так, что при запуске приложения оно и не запускалось автоматически в эмуляторе, и не присутствовало в меню.

Уже пробовал и переставлять все, что только можно, но ничего не помогает. Может кто-то сталкивался с такой проблемой. Как решали?

Работаю с IDEA 14. Вроде никаких ошибок не вылазит.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\android-sdk\tools\emulator.exe" -avd Nexus17 -netspeed full -netdelay none
emulator: device fd:784
HAXM is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode
creating window 40 81 335 557
emulator: emulator window was out of view and was recentered
emulator: UpdateChecker: skipped version check

Waiting for device.
"C:\Program Files (x86)\android-sdk\tools\emulator.exe" -avd Nexus17 -netspeed full -netdelay none
Device connected: emulator-5554
```

Сейчас попробовал просто запустить дефолтный helloworld

Файл манифеста. Ничего не менял.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="ru.smirnov.Application"
          android:versionCode="1"
          android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="17"/>
    <application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
        <activity android:name="MainActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Версия API эмулятора не меньше minSDK из манифеста? Активити главная там прописана с указанием, что её запускать надо?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб , добавил файл манифеста.  Если не ошибаюсь версию эмулятора брал 17.

Comment: "дефолтный helloworld" как я понял работает?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб,  в том-то и соль, что нет. Вот без понятия что такого произошло, что в эмулятор деплоиться приложение перестало.

Comment: А на реальном девайся работает? А ADB пробовали перезапускать?

Comment: Дополните вопрос gradle'ом, пожалуйста